# android listview doesn't update

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I am having a problem with using date range with a `listView` populated from a sqlite database, The code works perfectly however the issue i'm having is that the `listView` doesn't be updated (refreshed) when i choose another date range (when i touch the 'search' button again) , although the data adapter indeed gets the data from the database (made sure of that by using `logcat`)but doesn't print it in the `listView`. I can't use function `notifyDataSetChanged()`, it is not working, and whenever i use it after `add()` the app crashes.

Here is the code :-

```
public class ProductionCommentsActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private DBHandler dbHandler;
private ListView listView;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");//a variable for line break
private EditText editTextFrom, editTextTo;
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialogFrom, datePickerDialogTo;
private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
private String fromDate,toDate ; // variables to store the chosen dates

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_production_comments);

    dbHandler = new DBHandler(this, dbHandler.DATABASE_NAME_PRODUCTION, null, 1);
    try {
        dbHandler.copyDataBase();
        Log.d("copydb", dbHandler.getDatabaseName());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("copydb",e.getMessage());
    }

    //defining list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    //defining edit texts properties
    editTextFrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFrom);
    editTextFrom.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    editTextFrom.requestFocus();

    editTextTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);
    editTextTo.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    //setting up the date format
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    setDateTimeField();
    context = this;
}

//method to handle the date pickers properties
private void setDateTimeField() {
    editTextFrom.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) ProductionCommentsActivity.this);
    editTextTo.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) ProductionCommentsActivity.this);

    //creating a new instance of the calendar
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    //creating a pop up date picker
    datePickerDialogFrom = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        //getting the chosen date and setting its format
        //and writing the chosen date in the edit text
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            editTextFrom.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(newDate.getTime()));
            fromDate = editTextFrom.getText().toString();
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    datePickerDialogTo = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            editTextTo.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(newDate.getTime()));
            toDate = editTextTo.getText().toString();
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

// on click method to handle which edit text was touched
// and show the appropriate pop up calendar
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == editTextFrom) {
        datePickerDialogFrom.show();
    } else if(view == editTextTo) {
        datePickerDialogTo.show();
    }
}

//method to set format of date and attach the array adapter to the list view
public void searchDates(View view){
    if(!editTextFrom.getText().toString().matches("From:")
            && !editTextTo.getText().toString().matches("To:")) {
            setDateTimeField();
            getProductionComments(fromDate, toDate);
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d("fire",adapter.toString());
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter valid dates", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

//get production comments data
public void getProductionComments(String from, String to) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();

        String query = "SELECT Date,Item,Comments FROM ProductionCommentData WHERE Date " +
                "BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY Date DESC";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{from,to});

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Date"));
                    String item = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Item"));
                    String comments = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Comments"));
                    results.add("Date: " + date.substring(0, 10) + newline + newline +
                            "Item: " + item + newline + newline + comments);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"No Data was found for the chosen dates",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException se){
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), se.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is the layout code:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.qarun.qpcbeta.ProductionCommentsActivity"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Production Comments"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextFrom"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:editable="false"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:text="From:"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextTo"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextFrom"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:text="To:"
    android:focusable="false"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextTo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Search"
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:onClick="searchDates"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listView"/>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` 
Works in this case.
[If not try reloading the list]

Comment: where to use it exactly?

Comment: On your click event , or wherever you want to update it

Answer (score 0):

Don't recreate your adapter every time you do a search.

Class fields:

```
mAdapter // instantiate once
mListView // instantiate once
mResults // refresh with new data when available
```

This should happen in `onCreate()`

```
mListView = (ListView)findViewByid(//etc
mResults = new ArrayList<>();
//Init mAdapter here only
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mResults);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Then, in `searchDates(...)`, do

```
getProductionComments(fromDate, toDate);//Set mResults with new data
//Don't set adapter here
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //refresh adapter
```

Comment: unfortunately it is not working, when i touch the search button , nothing happens to the listView

Comment: Are you sure your data has changed between the search-button clicks? There is nothing I can see in your code to change the db's data. If it's the same data in the db every time you retrieve it, the ListView content will look the same.

Comment: of course it changes, i have made sure of that using the logcat